# Decode PNG image with Magick++

Tags: c++, image, image-processing, imagemagick, opencl

I need to put decoded RGBA data (from 32-bit PNG) in cl::Image2D, then (after some processing) write it back to Magick++ image with enqueueReadImage().

However, at the moment I do not see any way to access RGBA data directly in Magick++ image object. Is this possible? If not, what's the best way to get data in RGBA format from Magick++ object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Magick::Image::write function

```
Magick::Image im;
// read image ....

// only for RGBA !!!
size_t im_size = im.columns() * im.rows() * 4;
uint8_t * pixels = new uint8_t[im_size];
im.write(0, 0, im.columns(), im.rows(), "RGBA", ::Magick::CharPixel, pixels);
```