# Encode png to RGBA(8888) in ImageMagick (c++)

Tags: c++, sockets, image-processing, imagemagick, bufferedimage

I'm trying to convert a png to RGBA buffer and send it via tcp sockets, I've made a socket but i'm a begginer at image manipulation, how should I convert it to RGBA buffer and send it via sockets? I'm trying to use ImageMagick because it has a c++ api and i need to make this project work on c++

**Socket Server:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <Magick++.h>

using namespace std;

class Server_socket{
    fstream file;

    int PORT;
    
    int general_socket_descriptor;
    int new_socket_descriptor;

    struct sockaddr_in address;
    int address_length;

    public:
        Server_socket(){
            create_socket();
            PORT = 8050;

            address.sin_family = AF_INET; 
            address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; 
            address.sin_port = htons( PORT );
            address_length = sizeof(address);

            bind_socket();
            set_listen_set();
            accept_connection();

            file.open(".//Data//Server//image.png", ios::in | ios::binary);
            if(file.is_open()){
                cout<<"[LOG] : File is ready to Transmit.\n";
            }
            else{
                cout<<"[ERROR] : File loading failed, Exititng.\n";
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }

        void create_socket(){
            if ((general_socket_descriptor = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == 0) { 
                perror("[ERROR] : Socket failed");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            cout<<"[LOG] : Socket Created Successfully.\n";
        }

        void bind_socket(){
            if (bind(general_socket_descriptor, (struct sockaddr *)&address, sizeof(address))<0) {
                perror("[ERROR] : Bind failed");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            cout<<"[LOG] : Bind Successful.\n";
        }

        void set_listen_set(){
            if (listen(general_socket_descriptor, 3) < 0) {
                perror("[ERROR] : Listen");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            cout<<"[LOG] : Socket in Listen State (Max Connection Queue: 3)\n";
        }

        void accept_connection(){
            if ((new_socket_descriptor = accept(general_socket_descriptor, (struct sockaddr *)&address, (socklen_t*)&address_length))<0) { 
                perror("[ERROR] : Accept");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            cout<<"[LOG] : Connected to Client.\n";
        }

        void transmit_file(){
            std::string contents((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file)), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
            cout<<"[LOG] : Transmission Data Size "<<contents.length()<<" Bytes.\n";

            cout<<"[LOG] : Sending...\n";

            int bytes_sent = send(new_socket_descriptor , contents.c_str() , contents.length() , 0 );
            cout<<"[LOG] : Transmitted Data Size "<<bytes_sent<<" Bytes.\n";

            cout<<"[LOG] : File Transfer Complete.\n";
        }
};

int main(){
    Server_socket S;
    S.transmit_file();
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:**
I found a method from [this gentleman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13070008/decode-png-image-with-magick), i'm currently saving as txt to see what i got, can anyone confirm me if the data is correct (converted from png to rgba), and if it is, how can i send to my client socket as a buffer?

```
    InitializeMagick(NULL);
    Magick::Image image;
    image.read("/home/img.png");
    size_t image_size = image.columns() * image.rows() * 4;
    uint8_t * pixels = new uint8_t[image_size];
    image.write(0, 0, image.columns(), image.rows(), "RGBA", ::Magick::CharPixel, pixels);
    image.write("/home/img.txt");
```